# Как отклонить или принять запрос на использования микрофона\камеры в selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как отклонить или принять запрос на использования микрофона\камеры в selenium, если это вообще возможно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете изменить это в параметрах Google Chrome. Для этого

1. Создайте пустую директорию на вашем компьютере, для хранения профиля настроект. Лучше вынести это в отдельный профиль что бы по умолчанию не давать сайтом доступа. (Например C:\chrome-selenium-profile)
2. Откройте actor.yaml
3. Укажите настройки для использования виртуального микрофона и камеры

```
--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream
```

и

```
-use-fake-device-for-media-stream
```

4. После этого выключите всплывающий пуш апп

```
--disable-notification
```

5. Укажите путь до драйвера

```
selenium:
    desiredCapabilities:
        browserName: chrome
    chromeDriverExePath: C:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe
    chromeDriverExeArgs: ["--user-data-dir=C:\chrome-selenium-profile"]
```